# How to stop Reverse Proxy on particular node?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to stop only Reverse Proxy service/process without affecting everything else?
As far as I see the only way to disable it currently is to stop the whole windows Service Fabric Host Service which literally means to take node down.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @BulakaievOleksandr

I am not sure what kind of cluster you are running so I hope my assumption that you are talking about standalone cluster are correct.

As far as I know `ReverseProxy` is disable by default so in order to enable it the steps should be taken. I think if we reverse them - we should be able to **disable** `ReverseProxy`.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-setup#enable-reverse-proxy-on-standalone-clusters) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-setup#customize-reverse-proxy-behavior-using-fabric-settings) we should check the following:

In `ClusterConfig.json` please check that all `NodeTypes` have their `reverseProxyEndpointPort` property removed.

```
"properties": {
   ... 
    "nodeTypes": [
        {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            ...
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            ...
        }
    ],
   ...
}
```

Then please make sure that inside `fabricSettings` you have turned off the [ApplicationGateway/Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings#applicationgatewayhttp).

```
"fabricSettings": [
...
    {
        "name": "ApplicationGateway/Http",
        "parameters": [
             {
                 "name": "IsEnabled",
                 "value": "false"
             }
        ]
}
],
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe these settings are cluster wide thus Reverse Proxy will be fully disabled which is not acceptable in my case. I need to stop it on one single box where it doesn't perform correctly due to network issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These settings are cluster wide. I read your comment to @SteppingRazor I am not sure whether this is possible at current version of Service Fabric. The only thing I could advice is to try to performs [diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverse-proxy-diagnostics) of reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check this but I think it is possible. When you configure cluster configuration you can specify node types:

```
"nodeTypes": [
            {
                "name": "PrimaryNodeType",
                "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
                "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
                "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
                "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
                "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
                "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
                "applicationPorts": {
                    "startPort": "20001",
                    "endPort": "20031"
                },
                "isPrimary": true
            }
        ]
```

Notice that name for this node type is "PrimaryNodeType". You can add secondary node type and do not configure "reverseProxyEndpointPort". Use this node type for nodes you want to disable reverse proxy:

```
"nodes": [
        {
            "nodeName": "VM01",
            "iPAddress": "10.1.0.11",
            "nodeTypeRef": "PrimaryNodeType",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc0/r1",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
        },
        {
            "nodeName": "VM02",
            "iPAddress": "10.1.0.12",
            "nodeTypeRef": "SecondaryNodeType",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc0/r2",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
        },
```

It should work, although with Service Fabric you never know. Common sense solutions often do not work. Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you Razor. Unfortunately I need to do it in live QA environment on existing box which belongs to certain NodeType where ReverseProxy is already allowed. Turning it off for entire NodeType is not acceptable in my case. Moving box to different node type is long process (if possible at all) while I need to be able to take such box OOF in a matter of seconds.